# How to re-arrange polymer templated content?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

How would I define the following:

```html
<bf-tabnavigator>    
  <bf-tab>
    <bf-tab-title><a href="#home">Home</a></bf-tab-title>
    <bf-tab-content>My Content</bf-tab-content>
  </bf-tab>      
  <bf-tab>
    <bf-tab-title><a href="#b">B</a></bf-tab-title>
    <bf-tab-content>My B</bf-tab-content>
  </bf-tab>  

</bf-tabnavigator>
```

as a polymer element(s) that would effectively be transformed into

```html
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="home">My Content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="b">My B</div>    
 </div>
```

I can't generate the tabs in bf-tabnavigator element, as I can't do something like

```html
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">     
     <content select="bf-tab bf-tab-title"></content>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">     
     <content select="bf-tab bf-tab-content"></content>
 </ul>
```

because you can only select 1-deep in . But I can't generate an element for bf-tab, because I'd need to apply it twice in different flavours (once for the ul nav-tabs, once for the tab-content).

How is one meant to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. The shadowDOM also creates a barrier even if the output would look similar to your example. You wouldn't be able to use Bootstrap (or similar) CSS.

What you could do is to make the `<content>` invisible and clone it`s content into the`` element. This would result in a valid list.
When you reference your CSS inside your element you could even use CSS like Bootstrap's (not sure if this was the intention)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something clever with insertion points and `:nth-of-type` to render the correct title/content when it is active.

https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-experiments/blob/master/polymer-and-angular/together/elements/wc-tabs.html#L26

Comment: If it helps to have more examples, here's one more working one: https://github.com/dart-lang/spark/tree/master/widgets/lib/spark_split_view.